# WinUI 3 1.0 : Window Ready Event

Tags: c#, winui-3

I am trying to execute code when the window is ready.

Specifically, I am trying to make the window maximize. The issue is I cannot run this code synchronously after `InitializeComponent` because it is too soon (the window is not yet ready/ loaded/ shown, so setting the `Presenter` has no effect)

The issue is the `Window.Loaded` event doesn't seem to be exposed by WinUI 3 (version 1.0).

So here is my current hack. In the constructor (after `InitializeComponent`), I hook into one of the only events exposed by WinUI 3, `Activated`

```cs
Activated += MainWindow_Activated_FirstTime;
```

The issue is, this fires any time the window is focused, pretty  much. So the workaround is I just remove the event handler, inside the event handler

```cs
private void MainWindow_Activated_FirstTime(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    SetupWindow();
    Activated -= MainWindow_Activated_FirstTime;
}
```

(`SetupWindow` sets the window presenter)

Now, like I said, this *works*, but I think it's pretty hacky. I was wondering if there was a proper way to hook into the `Loaded` or maybe some equivalent event like `Ready` or `Rendered`. I really don't care what I hook into as long as it's better than this.

Comment: Can't you set that state upon initializing the window? eg. `Window window1 = new Window(); window1.State = WindowState.Maximize; window1.Show();` (code is just for demonstration, don't know the syntax in winui-3.

Comment: I don't think your solution is "hacky" at all. I don't see any other event which could be used in place of Loaded.

Answer (score 4):

If you have set the `Content` property of the window to a `FrameworkElement`, such as for example a `Panel` of any kind, you could handle the `Loaded` event of this one.

You could also use the `DispatcherQueue` to enqueue some work with low priority to be done as soon as the dispatcher thread is ready:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread().TryEnqueue(
        Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueuePriority.Low,
        new Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueueHandler(() =>
        {
            //...
        }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Win App Sdk 1.1.3, the event is now exposed

```
<Window
    x:Class="WindowsAppSdkTouchUI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AppExample"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Closed="Window_Closed"
    Activated="Window_Activated"> 

</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another less tricky way.

According to [XamlRoot is null in WinUI3 for Desktop preview4 #4242](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4242), Window's `Content.XamlRoot` is set on it's `Loaded`.

The following method will **asynchronously** wait until `Content.XamlRoot` is set, which ensures the window is loaded.

```
async Task UntilLoaded()
{
    while (this.Content.XamlRoot is null)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```